# MS Access SQL - How do I fix my Joins?

Tags: sql, ms-access, syntax

I'm not familiar with MS Access 2003-2007 SQL, but I have to maintain/extend a project that uses it. (The original author has left the company. Hooray for legacy code.) What I'm trying to do is join a number of related tables so that the query gives me the number of transactions for a particular user within a particular time range. The end result of this is that I want to see how many hours passed between an OUT event and the previous IN event for that user.

The code I have so far is as follows:

```
SELECT Directions.DirectionText, Transactions.Timestamp 
FROM Users 
LEFT JOIN AccessNumbers ON Users.AccessNumberID = AccessNumbers.AccessNumberID 
LEFT JOIN Transactions ON AccessNumbers.Number = Transactions.Number 
LEFT JOIN Events ON Transactions.Event = Events.EventNumber 
LEFT JOIN Readers ON Transactions.ReaderID = Readers.ReaderID 
LEFT JOIN Directions ON Readers.Direction = Direction.Direction 
WHERE 
  (Events.EventNum IN (1, 22)) AND 
  (Users.[Name] = "firstName") AND 
  (Users.Surname = "Surname") AND 
  (Transactions.Timestamp >=#2017-04-10 01:00:00#) AND 
  (Transactions.Timestamp <=#2017-05-09 14:57:30#) 
ORDER BY Transactions.Timestamp
```

The error I receive is "Syntax Error (missing operator in query expression 'Users.AccessNumberID = ... Direction.Direction'

I have also tried the following, to receive "Syntax Error on JOIN operation':

```
SELECT Directions.DirectionText, Transactions.Timestamp 
FROM Users 
LEFT JOIN (AccessNumbers ON Users.AccessNumberID = 
AccessNumbers.AccessNumberID)
ON (AccessNumbers.Number = Transactions.Number) 
ON (Transactions.Event = Events.EventNumber) 
ON (Transactions.ReaderID = Readers.ReaderID) 
ON (Readers.Direction = Direction.Direction) 
WHERE ...
```

I'm aware that the SQL needs parentheses, but I don't know where to place them.

Comment: Might be a typo in `LEFT JOIN Directions ON Readers.Direction = Direction.Direction`. It should be Directions.Direction. The rest looks fine on first glance. The second example looks fubar though, unless this is some special MS Access syntax that I am not aware of.

Comment: @daZza Thanks for the suggestion, but I still get the same errors after correcting the typo.

Comment: Access will put in the ()'s and overly so.  Additionally as these are left joins, the where clause criteria needs to be moved to the joins for everything but user, or the nulls from the left join will be removed on the tables events and transactions because of the where clause limits.

Comment: ok can you build it up join by join please, dto id where the issue is

Comment: you dont need your parenthesis if you are only using ands

Comment: what values are you looking for here please?    (Transactions.Timestamp >=#YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:SS#) AND 
  (Transactions.Timestamp <=#YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss#)

Comment: If you remove the events join and the limiting criteria does it work?  if so I'd move events to the end of the joins and then try to add back the where clause. or use a subquery where transaction event in (query)

Comment: I'm not sure and somebody may correct me but can you try to replace all of your LEFT JOIN to LEFT OUTER JOIN, it may be a SQL server only shorthand use of LEFT JOIN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had issues with Access trying to put in my parentheses for me in the past... especially with LEFT joins.  I'd normally parenthesize your first query like so:

```
SELECT Directions.DirectionText, Transactions.Timestamp 
FROM ((((Users 
LEFT JOIN AccessNumbers ON Users.AccessNumberID = AccessNumbers.AccessNumberID) 
LEFT JOIN Transactions ON AccessNumbers.Number = Transactions.Number) 
LEFT JOIN Events ON Transactions.Event = Events.EventNumber) 
LEFT JOIN Readers ON Transactions.ReaderID = Readers.ReaderID) 
LEFT JOIN Directions ON Readers.Direction = Directions.Direction 
WHERE 
  (Events.EventNum IN (1, 22)) AND 
  (Users.[Name] = "firstName") AND 
  (Users.Surname = "Surname") AND 
  (Transactions.Timestamp >=#2017-04-10 01:00:00#) AND 
  (Transactions.Timestamp <=#2017-05-09 14:57:30#) 
ORDER BY Transactions.Timestamp
```

Your second query would need more `LEFT JOIN` clauses thrown in to function.

Answer (score 1):

A simple trick is the following:
Add a closing parenthesis before each LEFT beyond the first.
Add an opening parenthesis after FROM for each LEFT beyond the first.

Result:

```
SELECT Directions.DirectionText, Transactions.Timestamp 
FROM ((((Users 
LEFT JOIN AccessNumbers ON Users.AccessNumberID = AccessNumbers.AccessNumberID 
) LEFT JOIN Transactions ON AccessNumbers.Number = Transactions.Number 
) LEFT JOIN Events ON Transactions.Event = Events.EventNumber 
) LEFT JOIN Readers ON Transactions.ReaderID = Readers.ReaderID 
) LEFT JOIN Directions ON Readers.Direction = Direction.Direction 
WHERE 
  (Events.EventNum IN (1, 22)) AND 
  (Users.[Name] = "firstName") AND 
  (Users.Surname = "Surname") AND 
  (Transactions.Timestamp >=#2017-04-10 01:00:00#) AND 
  (Transactions.Timestamp <=#2017-05-09 14:57:30#) 
ORDER BY Transactions.Timestamp
```

The result is the same as Sturgus says, but adding them this way makes sense to me. For layout purposes, you might move each closing parenthesis to the line above it.

Comment: Thanks for trying, but it's still giving me "Syntax Error in JOIN operation" for both.

Comment: I think the error occurs because `Direction.Direction` should be `Directions.Direction` and `(Users.[Name] = "firstName")` should be `((Users.Name) = "firstName")`. Otherwise, it's correct.

Comment: That first one was already pointed out by @daZza in the comments, second one makes no sense. I assumed you already fixed it.